# Multithreaded async write in Cassandra using Java Client

Tags: java, multithreading, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I am new to cassandra and Java also. I am trying to read a file with 1 million records and trying to dump it into cassandra db using `executorservice.Keyspace` is already there. But after the completion of the code I am getting only 10 records in the DB. What is wrong here? What am I supposed to change?

My Code is as below.

```
public class UsingThread {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, FileNotFoundException {

            Cluster cluster1 = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").withRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.INSTANCE).withLoadBalancingPolicy(new TokenAwarePolicy(new DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy())).build();
            final String csvFile = "C:/Users/AT/workspace1/catalog.csv";


            final  BufferedReader   br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));


              //Creating Session object
              final Session session = cluster1.connect("demo");


                  String query2 = "CREATE TABLE InventoryAB(Item_ID text PRIMARY KEY, "+"Desc1 text, "
                 + "Quality text, "
                 + "Node_No int, "
                 + "Type text, "
                 + "Curr text,"+ "Manu text, "+"Desc2 text, "+"Qty int);";
                session.execute(query2);

                PreparedStatement statement = session.prepare("INSERT INTO demo.InventoryAB(Item_ID, Desc1, Quality, Node_No, Type, Curr, Manu, Desc2, Qty) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

        int amountOfThreads = 10;
        ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(amountOfThreads);
        ExecutorCompletionService<String> tasks = new ExecutorCompletionService<String>(threadPool);
        long currentTimeE = System.nanoTime();
        for(int i=0; i < amountOfThreads; i++) {
            tasks.submit(new Callable<String>() {

                @Override
                public String call() throws Exception {

                    String ajay="";

                    String line = "";
                     while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        //System.out.println("Current thread is"+line);



                ajay=line;
                }


                    return ajay;
                }
            });
        }

            for(int i=0; i < amountOfThreads; i++) {
                Future<String> task = tasks.take();
                 String line = task.get();
                    String cvsSplitBy = ",";
                String[] column = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
                int h= Integer.parseInt(column[3]);
                int u= Integer.parseInt(column[8]);
                BoundStatement bind = statement.bind(column[0], column[1], column[2],h,column[4],column[5],column[6],column[7],u);
                session.executeAsync(bind);
            }

        threadPool.shutdown();
        long currentTimeF = System.nanoTime();
           long total2=currentTimeF-currentTimeE;
           System.out.println("Total time taken to load"+total2);
           try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        session.close();
          cluster1.close();

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried changing the number of threads from 10 to 1000 and now I got 1000 records in my column family.This code is supposed to write all the records from csv file to Cassandra using 10 threads only.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the logic of how you are reading the file. The thread keeps only the last line read.

But

**You should never access one file from several threads!!!**

In your example each thread got lucky and got at least one line but this is not guaranteed...

Moreover, all this is not needed.

```
session.executeAsync()
```

takes care of inserting into Cassandra asynchronously.

Comment: also missing loops in the threads so they only run once each. put the insert in the tasks and wrap in while loop

Comment: I have tried session.executeAsync but the number of writes per second I want is not achievable with it.So I am trying to use threads to increase the performance.It is taking more the 360 seconds on a two node cluster to dump all records in a csv file with 1 million records. Each record is barely 1 KB in size.Any suggestions?